# Creating a custom format specifier in __format__ method in python

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I was implementing my own format specifiers by overriding the `__format__()` method in my class. Now the trouble that I am having is that I am getting the below error. Is it because I can not use `%s` for any other format specification other than `str()` or am I doing something wrong here.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "test.py", line 66, in 
>       print("Dealer has {0:%r of %s}".format(NumberCard(1, Club)))
>     File "ch1.py", line 24, in **format**
>       result = format_spec.replace("%r", self.rank).replace("%s", self.suit)
>   TypeError: replace() argument 2 must be str, not int

```
class Card:

    insure = False

    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank
        self.hard, self.soft = self._points()

    def __str__(self):
        return "{rank}{suit}".format(**self.__dict__)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{__class__.__name__}(suit={suit!r}, rank={rank!r})".format(__class__=self.__class__, **self.__dict__)

    def __format__(self, format_spec):
        if format_spec == "":
            return str(self)
        else:
            result = format_spec.replace("%r", self.rank).replace("%s", self.suit)
            result = result.replace("%%", "%")
            return result

class NumberCard(Card):

    def _points(self):
        return int(self.rank), int(self.rank)


class Suit:

    def __init__(self, name, symbol):
        self.name = name
        self.symbol = symbol
```

I am passing my arguments as

`print("Dealer has {0:%r of %s}".format(NumberCard(1, Suit('Club', '♣'))))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert it?

```
def __format__(self, format_spec):
    if format_spec == "":
        return str(self)
    else:
        result = format_spec.replace("%r", str(self.rank)) # stringify your int
        result = result.replace("%s", str(self.suit.symbol)) # symbol instead class name
        result = result.replace("%%", "%")
```

Replace works on `replace(str,str)` - you can not replace a `str` with a `int` using it.

Doku: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace

Answer (score 2):

```
NumberCard(1, Suit('Club', '♣'))
```

So, the rank is an int

You're calling `replace("%r", self.rank)`

The error says `replace() argument 2 must be str, not int`

Use `str(self.rank)` in the replace instead